# Tcp Re-transmission timeout in a very short time?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I have two Windows 2012 R2 machines (122 and 115) hosted on the same VMWare host. We have a heartbeat at application layer between those two machines, from time to time there will be tcp re-transmission. Based on the wireshark log, it looks like re-transmission happens in 12-45 milliseconds and re-transmission could happen on either 122 or 115. For example, one of the latest log (this log is captured on the 122 machine) looks like:

1. At 10:30:42.654764 115 sends to 122: PSH+ACK Seq=28457 Ack=26914 Win=524032 Len=59
2. At 10:30:42.668642 122 sends to 115: ACK Seq=26914 Ack=28516 Win=524800 Len=0
3. At 10:30:42.668764 115 sends to 122: [Tcp Retransmission] PSH+ACK Seq=28457 Ack=26914 Win=524032 Len=59
4. At 10:30:42.668787 122 sends to 115: ACK Seq=26914 Ack=28516 Win=524800 Len=0 SLE=28457 SRE=28516

So it looks like 115 thinks that 122 is timed out after 34 milliseconds (even if 122 actually responds slightly earlier than that) and then tries a re-transmission. I tried to find this re-transmission timeout in the registry to no avail. (I was looking for something like InitialRtt) My questions:

1. Is 34 milliseconds a standard practice?
2. Could VMWare have anything to do with this?
3. Any reason why 122 is slow in the ACK? (The software on both ends are coded by us but don't think we ever try to adjust this value, I could be wrong on this since I didn't personally write the code).

Answer (score 0):

For established TCP connections, retransmission timeouts will be calculated dynamically depending on the RTT of the connection between client and server. Essentially, TCP will try to work out how long it should reasonably expect to wait to hear an ACK for a packet that it has sent out. If that timer expires, it will trigger a retransmission.

So based on your example, we can assume 122 receives a packet from 115. 122 sends an ACK for this packet but it never actually reaches 115. 115 thinks its original packet was never received by 122 so retransmits it after the retransmission timer expires. 122 receives this retransmission and sends another ACK.

Hope that helps.